# how to compute the distance between a matrix and its lower rank approximation?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, projective-space

I have a matrix $X$ and $Z$ a lower rank approximation of $X$ obtained using only few of the columns of $X$.

I would like to have a measure of how distant are $X$ and $Z$. In particular I would like something similar to what is usually done with PCA as explained [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/low-rank-approximations-1.html)

I need something like $std(X-\hat X)$ where $Projection(\hat X)=Z$ but that at the same time takes into account the correlation between the variables.

Suppose for example :
$X=(x_1, x_1, x_2, x_3)$ and $Z = (x_1, x_3)$ then $std(X-\hat X)= std((x_1,x_1,x_2,x_3) - (0,x_1,0,x_3))$ and I want this result to be equal to $std(x_3)$ and not $std(x_1) + std(x_3)$ because the information contained in $x_1$ is already contained in $Z$.

Suppose for example this  little python code

```
X=np.ndarray(shape=(10,20))
Z = X[:,[1,3,5]]
```

The optimal solution should have a theoretical explanation and a  python implementation of the answer

EDIT:  of possible interest [Sparse PCA](http://www.it.dtu.dk/projects/manifold/Papers/sparsepc.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute the distance between two matrices $X \in \mathbb V$ and $Y \in \mathbb V$ you will need a distance function on the space $\mathbb V$. One way to define such as distance is to use the Frobenius norm 
$\Vert X \Vert _F = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^M \sum_{j=1}^N X_{ij}^2}.$ Thus you will have $d_F(X,Y)=\Vert X - Y\Vert _F$. You can easily verify the required properties of $d_F(.,.)$, i) positivity, ii) triangle inequality iii) symmetry, to be a distance function. 
Please not that certain matrix spaces, such as positive definite matrices, define a specific geometry. For instance the positive definte matrices form a postive cone. For such manifolds there are more instrinsic distance functions, e.g. S-divergence.

Comment: Thanks for answering but the Frobenious norm is not good in my case. This does not take in consideration the correlation between variables. This is good in situation like pca where the covariance matrix is diagonal.

Comment: Can you describe a little bit in more detail what you mean by correlation between variables and what do you mean by the covariance matrix is diagonal ?